# Finding local minima for a signal

Tags: matlab

I have used the `findpeaks` function in MATLAB to find the locations and the values of the peaks (Local Maxima) in the signal.

```
[pks, locs] = findpeaks(X_Segments{nn},'MinPeakDistance', 20);
AverageDistance_Peaks(nn,:) = mean(diff(locs));
```

`X_Segments` contains the data.

Is there any function to extract the local minimums of the following graph?

[image: Graph shows the Local Maxima]
<sub>Graph shows the Local Maxima</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just negate your signal first. This will then give you the local minima.

```
% Pass a negative version of X_segments
[pks, locs] = findpeaks(-X_Segments{nn},'MinPeakDistance', 20);
AverageDistance_Peaks(nn,:) = mean(diff(locs));

% Change the sign back to be the correct one
pks = -pks;
```

Comment: I did mate, again, thank you so much, i am wondering should i change the sign of pks into -pks?